# Spring boot : delegateBuilder cannot be null on autowiring authenticationManager in custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-java-config

Hi i'm new to spring boot and trying implement the security to my rest apis.

i'm using spring boot 2.0.7.release

i have configures my WebSecurityConfig as following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
         PasswordEncoder encoder = new CustomPasswordEncoder(); 
         return encoder;
    }
    ....
   }
```

I have add the resource name so that i can point the to custom userDetailsService.

I have tried configuring authenticationManager Bean by came and pointing the bean by Qualifier authenticationManager bean still it the error remains same.

my pom.xml looks like for security

```
......
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
......
```

and my implemented UserServiceImpl is

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAOService userDao;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
         User user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
         if(user == null){
             throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
          }
         return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), getAuthority());
    }

    @Override
    public String login(LoginUser user) {
           // valid user if it exits then do the following

            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));

           //generate the token and do other process.
    }
```

following are the error logs. i have provided only mail errors

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/saikrishna/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delegateBuilder cannot be null
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/saikrishna/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delegateBuilder cannot be null
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [com/saikrishna/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delegateBuilder cannot be null
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityConfig' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'authenticationManagerBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delegateBuilder cannot be null
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: delegateBuilder cannot be null
  at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
```

Comment: you likely have a circular bean dependency

Comment: Just remove "authenticationManagerBean" method and try again. I think this bean is not require to explicitly create( i have done similar kind of thing without explicitly declaring it) .

Comment: @Spara i have checked my entire project there is no circular bean dependency

Comment: @sampathpremarathna i tried removing bean configuration for authenticationManagerBean before posting, since i am auto wiring in userservice - implementation class that class says bean not found

Comment: @Saikrishna Oh i havent done this for JWT , but for me configureGlobal implementation on WebSecurityConfig did work, for me that login method on "UserServiceImpl" was not required. This helped me in my case :https://o7planning.org/en/11543/create-a-login-application-with-spring-boot-spring-security-spring-jdbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to help you better, it is better if you indicate which reference you are following to implement JWT mechansim.

Conceptually, this part of the source code is wrong:

```
@Override
public String login(LoginUser user) {
       // valid user if it exits then do the following

        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));

       //generate the token and do other process.
}
```

See if the modifications below can help you

1) Consider using Java Config to declare your beans, in a seperate Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig{   
   @Bean
   protected UserDAOService daoService()
   {
      return new UserDAOServiceImpl();
   }
   @Bean
   protected UserDetailsService userDetailService( UserDAOService dao )
   {
      return new UserServiceImpl( dao );
   }
   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
     PasswordEncoder encoder = new CustomPasswordEncoder(); 
     return encoder;
   }
   @Bean
   public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception{                           {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
   }
}
```

2) Modification to your WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    protected void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService( userDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder );
    }

}
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: Thanks this work but one change 
AuthenticationManager i am configurating in web security config because it is extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and we are overriding